# .htaccess rewrite rule- query string to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using a `.htaccess` rewrite rule, how would I rewrite the following?..

I want to translate http://www.foo.com.au/soap?c=dem to http://www.foo.com.au/_pag/DEM.

I also want to translate http://www.foo.com.au/soap/dem to http://www.foo.com.au/_pag/DEM.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^soap /_pag/${uppercase:%1}? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^soap/(.+)$ /_pag/${uppercase:$1} [L,R=301]
```

It's not tested and have not written rewrite conditions in while.

Also need this in apache or virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteMap uppercase int:toupper
```

Comment: Thanks- didn't work though. It ended up returning the path: http://foo.com.au/var/www/foo.bar.com.au___443/html/_pag/?c=dem... so it is returning the filesystem path on top of that..

Comment: Have added missing leading slashes in target URIs. Try now.